# Validate password rule on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've a user registration form and the user need to enter password. I've some password rules like must contain 8 characters, numbers and Upper case etc.

How can I show if the user met the password criteria while typing and showing it in a small popup or something similar?

Currently I've code that shows a tick mark only if he met these criteria(like 8 chars,1 upper case and 1 digit)

```
  <td>
            <table><tr>
                <td>
              <input type="password" name="password"
              size="25" tabindex="<%= get_next_tabindex(@content_data) %>"
              value="<%= @content_data['password'] %>"
              onKeyUp="validatePassword(this)">
          </td>
          <td id="password_Valid_Image" style="display:none">
            <%=  image_tag(
                "/assets/20/tick-icon.png",
                :alt => "") %>
          </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
```

```
var is_Password_Valid = false;
var lower_Case = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"];
var upper_Case = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]

function validatePassword(password_Input){
  is_Password_Valid = true;

  if(password_Input.value.length < 8){
    is_Password_Valid = false;
    drawPasswordValid(is_Password_Valid);
    return;
  }

  var found_Chars = 0;

  for(var i=0; i<lower_Case.length; i++){
      if(password_Input.value.indexOf(lower_Case[i]) > -1){
        found_Chars++;
      }
  }

  if(found_Chars == 0){
    is_Password_Valid = false;
    drawPasswordValid(is_Password_Valid);
    return;
  }

  found_Chars = 0;

  for(var i=0; i<upper_Case.length; i++){
      if(password_Input.value.indexOf(upper_Case[i]) > -1){
        found_Chars++;
      }
  }

  if(found_Chars == 0){
    is_Password_Valid = false;
    drawPasswordValid(is_Password_Valid);
    return;
  }

  found_Chars = 0;

  for(var i=0; i<numbers.length; i++){
      if(password_Input.value.indexOf(numbers[i]) > -1){
        found_Chars++;
      }
  }

  if(found_Chars == 0){
    is_Password_Valid = false;
    drawPasswordValid(is_Password_Valid);
    return;
  }

  drawPasswordValid(is_Password_Valid);

  }
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be a bit annoying for the user to get a popup as they are typing, or do you want the window to popup on submit?

Comment: No its not like that. If you dont mid plz click on this page the ebay registration page and plz click on password filed
https://scgi.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?RegisterEnterInfo
I want something like that

Answer (score 3):

Take a look on existing jQuery plugins: [10 Password Strength Meter Scripts For A Better Registration Interface](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/10-password-strength-meter-scripts-for-a-better-registration-interface/)

```
function check(str) {

    var length = new RegExp('^[\\d\\w]{6,}$');
    var digit = new RegExp('[\\d]+');
    var upper = new RegExp('[A-Z]+');

    return length.test(str) && digit.test(str) && upper.test(str);

}

alert(check('asasasA77'));
```

code: http://jsfiddle.net/wYDej/1/

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I want something different, I don't want a password strength meter. I want the user met the password rule criteria like he entered 6 Characters,1 Upper case and 1 digit.

Comment: Check sample. I've completed it with 3 regular expressions if it's what you need. I don't know, but probably it can be done with single expression.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not looking for a strength meter and you just want to show the user some information, check out jQuery bubble popup: http://www.vegabit.com/jquery_bubble_popup_v2/